# How do I replace a certain class when running some JUnit tests?

Tags: java, junit, mocking

I'm using Java 6 with JUnit 4.8.1 (and Maven 3.0.3).  For certain JUnit tests, I want to replace a class that some of the tests are dependent on (qualified as com.myco.clearing.product.server.cache) with my own version of this class (which has the same public method signatures).  What is an elegant way to do this?

Note that some of the JUnit tests don't invoke the com.myco.clearing.product.server.cache.Cache class directly, but rather call classes that rely on this class.  Even in these indirect cases, I want my version of the class to be used.

Thanks for any help along these lines, - Dave

Comment: Wait, are your _tests_ dependent on Cache? Or is the unit under test the one which depends on Cache? (I know Cache is just an example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to say *exactly* what to do here, but in general:

1. Use some IoC techniques - contructor, setter injection.
2. Use a mocking framework to mock your objects, I would recommend
   Mockito.

So, for example, if you have a class that uses `com.myco.clearing.product.server.cache.Cache` let's call it `Foo`. And you use now like this:

```
class Foo {
 private Cache _cache = new Cache( ... );
}
```

If possible, change it to something like this:

```
class Foo {
    private Cache _cache;

    public Foo( Cache cache ) {
      _cache = cache;
    }

    public Foo() {
      this( new Cache() );
    }
}
```

Then you may be able to inject in a mocked version of the `Cache` class. I say "may be able to" as it depends on the `Cache` class. If it is final, has a bunch of static methods, etc. then you have more to deal with.